# Count certain words in string javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, var

I am looking for a way to count certain words on a string.

```
$string = "How are you doing today? You are such a nice person!";
```

My goal is to count how many "are" in the $string variable.

Desire result: 2

Comment: What about words like; Bare, Care, Dare, Fare.. do they count?

Comment: `"How are you doing today? You are such a nice person!".match(/\bare\b/g).length`

Comment: @megawac: that should be the answer

Comment: This is case-sensitive or insensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var count =  yourString.match(/\bare\b/g); 
count = count? count.length : 0;  //checking if there are matches or not.
console.log(count);
```

Comment: I think the `|!` is unnecessary (and a sentence could and with other symbols anyway, e.g. `We are?`), the `\b` suffices.

Comment: @IngoBürk yeah you are right.. It was just a test mentioned by you in below comments :) anyway you can do like this `/\bare(\b|[!?])/g`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = "are you bare footed?";
console.log(string.split(/\bare\b/).length - 1);
```

Comment: The sentence `Are you home? You are such a nice person!` Output: 1.

Comment: @ErikPhilips He didnt mention anything about case sensitivity, I believe.

Comment: +1 I'm also a fan of not using regex when applicable.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither this nor a simple regex will do. Example: `Foo are baz barefoot. We totally are!`. It should give two matches. Your method will give three. Adding spaces around the word also won't do.

Comment: this is not possible without using regex when there are words like `fare` `aware` which contains "are" in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "How are you doing today? You are such a nice person!";
var matchs;
matchs = str.match(/are/gi);
alert(matchs.length);
```

try this javascript match  it returns match string as array format, and length method returns how many array index match.

Answer (score 0):

try below.

```
    var temp = "How are you doing today? You are such a nice person!.";

var count = countOcurrences(temp,"are");  

alert(count);

function countOcurrences(str, value){
   var regExp = new RegExp(value, "gi");
   return str.match(regExp) ? str.match(regExp).length : 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$string = "How are you doing today? You are such a nice person!";

var count = $string.match(/are/g);  

alert(count.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var string = "How are you doing today? You are such a nice person!";
var num = string.match(/are/g).length;
alert(num);
```

Here is [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/yLEMk/)

Answer (score -1):

You can also try something like this:

```
var temp = "How are you doing today? You are such  a nice person!.";
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0;i< temp.split(' ').length; i++)
{   
    if(temp.split(' ')[i] === "are"){
     arr.push(temp.split(' '));

     }

}
alert(arr.length)
```